# Reading files of different types -Fuse

Tags: java, file-io, fuse

I am writing a Java Application (FUSE File system) . This app read files from file system of different file types such as text, images, pdf, audio and video files.. etc.

In file read method I coded as:

```
    public int read(final String path, final ByteBuffer buffer, final long size, final long offset, final FileInfoWrapper info)
{

    String contentOfFile=null;
    try {
        contentOfFile= readFile(mirroredFolder+path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String s = contentOfFile.substring((int) offset,
            (int) Math.max(offset, Math.min(contentOfFile.length() - offset, offset + size)));
    buffer.put(s.getBytes());
    return s.getBytes().length;
}
```

But it doesn't read all file types correctly. Please see the image below in which I have shown the error messages created while opening files.

[image: error in reading]

As shown, The code reads only one type of files files correctly and the rest pop up error messages.

Can somebody modify my code, so that it reads all types of files universally.

---

-Added later-

(Fuse log) Stack Trace

```
Jun 18, 2014 11:13:36 AM org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360 getattr
INFO: [/Untitled Folder/picture.png] Method succeeded. Result: 0
Jun 18, 2014 11:13:38 AM org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360 open
INFO: [/Untitled Folder/picture.png] Method succeeded. Result: 0
Jun 18, 2014 11:13:38 AM org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360 read
INFO: [/Untitled Folder/picture.png] Method succeeded. Result: 0
Jun 18, 2014 11:13:38 AM org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360 flush
INFO: [/Untitled Folder/picture.png] Method succeeded. Result: 0
Jun 18, 2014 11:13:38 AM org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360 lock
INFO: [/Untitled Folder/picture.png] Method succeeded. Result: -38
release called: Path=/Untitled Folder/picture.png
Jun 18, 2014 11:13:38 AM org.organization.upesh.FirstMaven.SFS_360 release
INFO: [/Untitled Folder/picture.png] Method succeeded. Result: 0
```

Program throws no error. But its the interface of the applications (i.e. pdf reader, libre office reader, picture viewer etc) that give error message while reading file, because my custom fuse file system reads the files in wrong way.

Comment: It's better to provide a stack trace than an image. Also, I don't see an image linked.

Comment: You are reading files into String. This will work only for text files with correct encoding. You have to operate on raw bytes only.

Comment: @Banthar, I will read different type of files, is there a way so that my program could able to read different types of files, not only text.

Comment: There seems to be several FUSE for Java implementations. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Bantar Fuse-JNA . But its not the issue with fuse, the issue is with my java code for file reading.